# Reason for the inability to concatenate strings and ints in Python

Tags: python, string, int, operator-overloading, concatenation

It is well documented in numerous that `str` is required to convert ints to strings before they can be concatenated:

```
'I am ' + str(n) + ' years old.'
```

There must be a fundamental reason why Python does not allow

```
'I am ' + n + ' years old.'
```

and I would like to learn what that reason is. In my project, I print a lot of numbers and end up with code like this.

```
'The GCD of the numbers ' + str(a) + ', ' + str(b) + ' and ' + str(c) + ' is ' + str(ans) + '.'
```

It would be much prettier if I could drop 'str'. And here's what makes my experience particularly vexing. I'm working with SymPy, so I have code like this:

```
'Consider the polynomial ' + (a*x**2 + b*x + c)
```

This works 99% percent of the time because we overloaded the '+' for SymPy expressions and strings. But we can't do it for ints and, as a result, this code fails when a=b=0 and the polynomial reduces to an integer constant! So for that outlier case, I'm forced to write:

```
'Consider the polynomial ' + str(a*x**2 + b*x + c)
```

So again, the solution 'string' + str(int) is straightforward, but the purpose of my post is to understand by Python doesn't allow 'string' + int the way, for instance, Java does.

Comment: Because explicit is better than implicit; concatenation requires explicit conversion, objects are not normally coerced implicitly.

Comment: You should really learn about `str.format()`:  `'The GCD of the numbers {}, {} and {} is {}.'.format(a, b, c, ans)`. Python 3.6 and up offer `f` strings:  `f'The GCD of the numbers {a}, {b} and {c} is {ans}.'`

Comment: Some explanations could be found here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304445/202154

Comment: @MartijnPieters Strange, but you can do the same with print("I am ", n, " years old.") and nobody complains about implicit conversion for some reason. So replacing "+" operator with comma suddenly makes it ok ?

Comment: @BulgarSadykov `print()` **explicitly** converts all arguments to strings using `str()`, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print): *All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does*. `print()` has an explicit, narrow use case, the `+` operator has a far broader use case that goes way beyond strings.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **","** instead of **"+"** :

```
a=4
x=5
b=6
c=5
n=100
my_age="I am",n,"Years old"
print("I may say",my_age)

print('Consider the polynomial ' ,(a*x**2 + b*x + c))
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the `+` operator.

When using the `+` operator, depending on the `a` and `b` variable types used in conjuncture with the operator, two functions may be called:

`operator.concat(a, b)` or `operator.add(a, b)`

The `.concat(a, b)` method returns `a + b` for sequences.

The `.add(a, b)` method returns `a + b` for numbers.

This can be found in the pydocs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

Python doesn't implicitly convert variable types so that the function "works". That's too confusing for the code. So you must meet the requirements of the `+` operator in order to use it.

Comment: So is there a reason why the designers of Java decided that this would be a good idea and the designers of Python decided that this would be a bad idea? What's the fundamental design difference?

Comment: @Lem.ma I'm not really sure why, but I'm positive it has to do with how the two languages chose to handle type coercion. I recommend you read about String Formatting for some cases in lieu of concatenation. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).