# why integer cannot add with string

Tags: python, string, integer, output, typeerror

```
n=int(input('Enter any number :'))
str1=""
for i in range(1,n+1):
  str1+=n
print(str1)
```

I tried the above mentioned code and it gave me typeerror and My expectation is
e.g
n=5
output : 12345

Comment: cast n to a string before concatenating `str1 += str(n)`  BTW why are you iterating from 1 to n+1 instead of 0 to n?

Answer (score 1):

There are two error in your code:

1. You attempt to concatenate `n` instead of `i`.
2. It is not possible to concatenate an integer to string value.

Now, this is my suggestion:

```py
n=int(input('Enter any number :'))
str1=""
for i in range(1,n+1):
  str1+=str(i)
print(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you have to cast your integer into string before concatenating,
Use below, this method is called as **'list comprehension'**

```
 n=int(input('Enter any number :'))
''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you try to concatenate a string with an integer using the + operator, you will get a runtime error. That's because Python is [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language. There are various other ways to perform this operation. I found a lot of similar questions asked before on Stack Overflow. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201680/why-cant-python-concatenate-a-string-and-int) one might give you your answer.